# LibreOffice calc wrong average

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

There's probably something I'm doing wrong which I'm not seeing.
But the average being calculated seems completely off.

This is an extract of the data:

```
    R       S       T
29  3,90 %  0,01 %  0,98 %
30  4,22 %  0,57 %  1,62 %
31  4,53 %  1,06 %  2,18 %
32  4,81 %  1,49 %  2,68 %
33  5,07 %  1,87 %  3,13 %
34  5,31 %  2,20 %  3,53 %
35  5,54 %  2,50 %  3,90 %
36  5,76 %  2,77 %  4,23 %
37  5,96 %  3,02 %  4,54 %
38  6,15 %  3,24 %  4,83 %
39  6,33 %  3,44 %  5,09 %
40  6,50 %  3,62 %  5,34 %
```

The formula for `S40` is `=AVERAGE(R29:R40)`

The formula for `T40` is `=SUM(R29:R40)/12`

Is `AVERAGE` not the right function? What should I be using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it was not recalculating the results, not that the average was wrong.

Comment: I don’t know;  it seems to me that this ***is*** the answer.